# Threading and IEnumerable; "Collection Was Modified"-exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq

Imagine that in the class below, one thread gets the IEnumerable-object and starts iteration over the elements. While in the middle of the iteration, another thread comes along and add a new entry to the library_entries via the Add-method. Would a "Collection was modified"-exception be thrown in the iteration? Or would the lock prevent the adding of the element until the iteration is complete? Or neither?

Thanks!

```
public static class Library
{
    private static List<string> library_entries = new List<string>(1000000);

    public static void Add(string entry)
    {
        lock (library_entries)
            library_entries.Add(entry);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetEntries()
    {
        return library_entries.Where(entry => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry));
    }
}
```

Comment: You could look into .net 4's concurrent collections to check if one of them is useful for what you want to do(I'm not sure about what you want).

Answer (score 4):

No, you won't get the exception, you are using a Linq query.  It is much worse, it will fail unpredictably.  The most typical outcome is that the same item gets enumerated twice, although anything is possible when the List re-allocates its internal storage during the Add() call, including an IndexOutOfRangeException.  Once a week, give or take.

The code that calls GetEntries() and consumes the enumerator must acquire the lock as well.  Locking the Where() expression is not good enough.  Unless you create a copy of the list.

Answer (score 1):

locking wouldn't help at all, since the iteration doesn't use locking. I recommend rewriting the `GetEntries()` function to return a copy.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetEntries()
{
    lock(lockObj)
    {
        return library_entries.Where(entry => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Note this returns a consistent snapshots. i.e. it won't return newly added objects when you're iterating.

And I prefer to lock on a private object whose only purpose is locking, but since the list is private it's no real problem, just a stylistic issue.

You could also write your own iterator like this:

```
int i=0;
bool MoveNext()
{
  lock(lockObj)
  {
      if(i<list.Count)
          return list[i];
      i++;
  }
}
```

If that's a good idea depends on your access patterns, lock contention, size of the list,... You might also want to use a Read-Write lock to avoid contention from many read accesses.

Comment: And by returning a copy you lose any advantage of deferred execution.

Comment: Yes one loses deferred execution that way, and it could result in an expensive allocation. Alternatively one could devise some kind of thread safe iterator, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The static `GetEntries` method doesn't perform any lock on the static `library_entries` collection => it is not thread-safe and any concurrent calls on it from multiple threads might break. The fact that you have locked the Add method is fine but enumerating is not a thread safe operation so you must lock on it as well if you intend to call the GetEntries method concurrently. Also because this method returns an `IEnumerable<T>` it won't do anything on the actual list until you start enumerating which could be outside of the `GetEntries` method. So you could add a `.ToList()` call at the end of the LINQ chaining and thenlock the entire operation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an exception would be thrown - you aren't locking on a common object. Also, a lock in the `GetEntries` method would be useless, as that call returns instantly. The locking would've to occur while iterating.